# Geo Add-on Choropleth Widget not found

Tags: visualization, orange, geospatial, heatmap

I am trying to create a Choropleth map using the Chorolpeth widget from the Geo Add-on in Orange. However, this widget is not appearing? Any ideas?

My current version: Orange version 3.24.1 for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Try reinstalling/updating Orange to the latest version.
2. Try reinstalling/updating the Geo package in Orange, from the Add-ons menu, to the latest version.

I am currently running **Orange version 3.27.1 and Geo version 0.2.8** and the Choropleth widget appears.